# adding padding to 100% width div in non bootstrap page

Tags: html, css

i have creating a layout in which width of a div is 100% given and i want to add padding in it but its breaking the page please refer the code below

**HTML**

```
<div class="main">
  <div class="inner">
    some text
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.main{
  width:100%;
  padding:10px;
}
.inner{
  width:100%;
}
```

[fiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/s87vxt3c/1/)
Thanks in advance

Comment: remove width : 100% for both class and add this css to make div 100% *{ margin : 0 auto; }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

well using an div means its already `100%` width by default so if you can remove width then it will work fine but may be there is something because of which you need to use width then you can use following css.

**css**

```
.main{
  width:100%;
  padding:10px;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

this will automatically reduce the padding from width and you will see 100% div with padding widthout any breaking

Comment: @Gaurav Aggrawal can you please explain, why this works?

Comment: @SouhaiebBesbes As described above `box-sizing:border-box;` css property merge padding in width. as in above example this property will decrease padding in width and merge it so the final width will be 100% with padding.

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove `width 100%` from `inner` and add `padding` to that `div` **[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/s87vxt3c/3/)**

```
.main{
  width:100%;     
  background:#000;
}
.inner{
  padding:10px;
  color:#fff;
}
```

**Update:** As you are using `#inner` in `div`, its by default take `100% width`..So no need to specify width for inner you can check it **[here](https://jsfiddle.net/s87vxt3c/5/)**

Comment: if i am writing width:100% then its might be necessary i cant remove it

Answer (score 0):

use this css

```
.main{
  padding: 10px;
  width: calc(100% - 20px);
  background:#000;
}
```

**[JSFiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/badge2033/980fmauo/1/)**

As GLP mentioned, you don't need to specify 100% width on the inner div because it's the default width for all block elements.